# Liferay's default guest page and it's purpose in a Website

Tags: liferay, administration

I'm currently building a website for a company, that will for the moment contain 3-5 static pages (i.e, just content). User registration may be added in time to come.

Now, I've been reading through the Liferay docs, forums and wiki, and I'm still pretty unclear on the approach to take in designing this website:

1. If I were to model my company Website as an organization in Liferay where I would have the public pages of the Website, what would be the purpose of the default guest page? (/web/gues/home)? Do I remove this and redirect the guest to my organization? If so, how do I do this?
2. Who is the creator of an organization in the real world? Is this site administrator? or the person responsible for adding content?
3. Who is the creator of an organization in Liferay? Is this the administrator to Liferay (i.e the default Test user)?

Answer (score 4):

1. The best way to do is is to put your pages in the Public Pages of your organization and setup a virtual host (see Manage Pages -> Virtual Hosts in the Control Panel) for those pages. This way, www.my-homepage.com will redirect to the public pages of your organization. You should of course be owner of the domain and link the domain to the IP address of the server the website runs on.
2. In Liferay, by default only users with the role of Administrator can add organizations. For managing content you should setup other roles. Create f.e. a Content Editor role and add permissions for the Web Content portlet (Create Content, Approve, Edit, Delete, View in Control Panel). This also answered your third question.

Answer (score 0):

Add this lines of code in your portal-ext.properties

```
    mail.session.mail.pop3.host=pop.gmail.com  
    mail.session.mail.pop3.password=PASSWORD
    mail.session.mail.pop3.port=110   
    mail.session.mail.pop3.user=USER    
    mail.session.mail.imap.host=imap.gmail.com    
    mail.session.mail.imap.port=993
    mail.session.mail.store.protocol=imap    
    mail.session.mail.transport.protocol=smtp    
    mail.session.mail.smtp.host=smtp.gmail.com    
    mail.session.mail.smtp.password=PASSWD
    mail.session.mail.smtp.user=USERID@gmail.com    
    mail.session.mail.smtp.port=465    
    mail.session.mail.smtp.auth=true    
    mail.session.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true    
    mail.session.mail.smtp.socketFactory.class=javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory
```

- Please user your password in place of PASSWD and your gmail user id in place of USERID.
  By three different ways we can configure mail server in Liferay. I am using Liferay 6.2 and initially I got an error that could not connect to smtp host localhost port 25 in liferay by using different code. So I used above code and my mail server is configured properly and my application is able to send mail to the user in forgot password case.

And please see this link. This link help me to solve the issue.

https://www.permeance.com.au/web/tim.telcik/home/-/blogs/how-do-i-configure-liferay-portal-to-use-google-mail

Thanks

asif aftab